# High memory consumption in typescript

Tags: ts-node

I run a very simple test program and it consumes 130 MB of memory.
  What caused this problem?

> ts-node --files test.ts

```
// module: tset.ts

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('ok!')
}, 10000);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ts-node need much memory for transfile (ts -> js) so it has big size than normal node execution env.